Performance issues with iOS 17's MapPolyline in SwiftUI
I'm currently trying to implement a new feature into my transit app, which permits users to locate their busses, trams, etc onto a map. This feature's about to show on the map, the paths that a selected line takes. In order to do that, I'm using the MapPolyline component recently added into MapKit with iOS 17. Everything works fine, except for the performance. As said before, it lets users locate busses, and their position is updated every 5 seconds. Of course, I need to use the Annotation component, and before adding MapPolyline the performance was fine. As you may know, the way that SwiftUI works is that when it needs to update the view, it'll re-render the entire view. Though, as my polyline coordinates array contains a certain amount of data, every 5 seconds, my map updates the annotations position, but it also re-renders the polylines, which causes a pretty visible stutter, and this is very annoying when using the map.
Here is the entire Swift file that contains the view, and the coordinates management that is displayed with the polylines onto the map.
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

@available(iOS 17, *)
struct LineMapViewWithPolylines: View {
    @State var pathsCoordinates: [[CLLocationCoordinate2D]] = []
    
    @Binding var mapRegion: RegionWrapper
    @Binding var services: [Service]
    @Binding var selectedService: Service?
    @Binding var userPositionBtnAppearance: String
    @Binding var showsUserLocation: Bool
    
    var line: Line
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(position: .constant(MapCameraPosition.region(mapRegion._region)), interactionModes: [.pan, .zoom]) {
            if showsUserLocation {
                UserAnnotation()
            }
            
            ForEach(services) { service in
                Annotation("", coordinate: service.coordinates) {
                    Button {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                            selectedService = service
                        }
                        withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 1.0, blendDuration: 0.5)) {
                            self.mapRegion = RegionWrapper(latitude: service.latitude - (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? 0 : 0.015), longitude: service.longitude, latitudeDelta: 0.06, longitudeDelta: 0.06)
                        }
                    }
                    label: {
                        VStack {
                            if(line.lineName == "Tram A" || line.lineName == "Tram B" || line.lineName == "Tram C" || line.lineName == "Tram D") {
                                TramIcon(orientation: service.orientation)
                            }
                            else if(line.lineName == "BatCUB") {
                                FerryIcon(orientation: service.orientation)
                            }
                            else {
                                BusIcon(orientation: service.orientation)
                            }
                            
                            Text(service.vehicle.parkId)
                                .foregroundColor(Color("ReversedDarkMode"))
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .font(.system(size: 14))
                                .offset(y: service.orientation == nil ? -48 : -60)
                                .scaledToFill()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            ForEach(pathsCoordinates, id: \.self) { coordinates in
                MapPolyline(coordinates: coordinates)
                    .stroke(Color(line.lineType), lineWidth: 3)
            }
        }
        .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { _ in
                    userPositionBtnAppearance = "location"
                }
        )
        .onAppear {
            LinePaths.getOrderedPathsByLine(lineId: line.id, withCoordinates: true) { paths in
                paths.forEach { backAndForthPaths in
                    backAndForthPaths.forEach { path in
                        pathsCoordinates.append(contentsOf: path.coordinates.map { coordinates in
                            coordinates.map { CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: $0[1], longitude: $0[0]) }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Anybody knows if there's a way to re-render the map content without re-rendering the polylines, or if there's another solution to fix this performance issue? Thanks in advance!

I've tried to retrieve the paths in another thread, but the thing that this has nothing to do with the fact that the view re-renders itself.


How about breaking down the map content into smaller MapContents? It's just like how you should break down big Views into smaller Views. This can probably prevent SwiftUI from updating things unnecessarily.

@Sweeper thanks for your answer! I'm not sure if we can call the Annotation or either the MapPolyline component without being into a Map closure?

You can. Similar to how you create Views by conforming to View, create a struct that conforms to MapContent. Put the annotations and poly lines in the body property in exactly the same way as how you create a custom View.

@Sweeper it seems to do nothing, as each time SwiftUI reloads the view, it has to reload the entire view. I've tried to put at least the ForEach(services) { service in part into another file, but the issue stil happens... :/

@Sweeper my bad, I've talked too fast. I've tried to decompose the view, and in fact, I read that a view component is called each time that the view has to refresh itself, but the body isn't called if the content doesn't have to renewed. Actually, my map's performance isn't as bad as before, even though it sometimes still has a bit of stutter. Thanks a lot for your aid :)
